# Direction of friction!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

[image: How can I assume the direction of friction acting on the block to determine the external force necessary to keep the block at rest]

How can I assume the direction of friction acting on the block to determine the external force necessary to keep the block at rest.

Comment: could go either way

Comment: It's vertical - no other option!

Comment: I understand it could go either way, and its the sum of net vertical forces which keeps it at rest. But in the solution, they have taken it downwards. So any explanations over that assumption, because I find it absurd to assume any direction with this much information.

Comment: That assumption of course comes from some more information or knowledge about the situation. There must be some info you have forgotten to show, otherwise that assumption is absolutely unfounded

Comment: Did they use "least", "greatest", "minimum", or "maximum" anywhere in the question?...

Answer (score 5):

There is not enough information given to determine the direction of the frictional force.
The two known vertical forces are the weight of the block $mg$ and the upward component of the force $\vec F$ which is $F \sin 37^\circ$.

From the relative magnitudes of these two vertical forces you can determine the direction of the frictional force for static equilibrium.

So you need to decide whether $mg > F\sin 37^\circ$ or  $mg < F\sin 37^\circ$ so it might well be that there is more than one answer for the magnitude of the force $\vec F$ to achieve static equilibrium?

Answer (score 1):

Given the diagram, you can compute the net force on the block:

$$F_{net} = -mg + F\sin 37 + F_f$$

Where $F_f$ is the force of friction.

Now friction appears to counter the direction in which the object would move without friction; it follows that

1. When $-mg + F\sin 37 < 0$, the object would want to move down and friction will point up
2. When {-mg + F\sin 37 > 0$, the object would want to move up and friction will point down

At the same time we know that the maximum friction force will be $F_f = \mu F \cos 37$. We can therefore make a diagram that shows the range of values of $F$ for which the mass doesn't move - and this will include some values of $F$ for which the friction prevents the mass from sliding down, and others that prevent the mass from sliding up:

[image]

This diagram shows the force of gravity (black), the vertical component of the external force (red), the sum of these two (blue), and the range of friction forces (limits shown in green).

As long as the blue curve is between the two green curves, there is a sufficient friction available to keep the object still. Obviously, with the lowest external force, friction must be pointing up to support the mass; as the external force gets larger, it eventually reverses the direction of the friction.\

Answer (score 0):

The frictional force holds the cube at rest on the wall. So, the friction vector is in the upwards direction. The magnitude of the frictional force corresponds to the normal force of F to the wall.

Comment: @Can we be sure it is the friction force that holds the cube, not the upward component of the external force?

Comment: Not just only friction foce hold the cube, summing of vertical  components of F force and the friction force is carry cube's weight.

Comment: But if the total holding force is directed upwards, does it mean that both friction and the vertical component of the external force are directed upwards?

Comment: Yes, in this question, both forces are upward direction. It doesn't matter F force's direction. Friction force's direction is opposite side to moving direction of cube.

Comment: This statement seems to lack proof. If the upward component of the external force is greater than the force of gravity, the friction will be directed downwards in equilibrium. I cannot be sure that equilibrium is possible under such condition, but it is not obvious that it is not possible.

Comment: I don't know mass and F force. If I know them and I couldn't make a prediction of friction's direction, I will choose one direction as I wish. For cube rest on wall, I will make my calculation. End of calculation I will find friction force, if my assumption of direction is true, result will be positive, otherwise negative.

Comment: I am not sure that works for friction force. What's more important though, you don't have proof of your statement that the friction force is directed upwards (no matter what values of $f$ and $mg$ are).

Answer (score 0):

Well , the force may have a range of values if friction is f then F+f=mg if Fless than mg otherwise it would be F=mg+f
So the direction of friction obviously depends whether F is less than or greater than mg if less then f is upwards or else it is downwards.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) You can see a help section on typesetting formulas [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) :)